# transitionFromViewController stops animations in the from view

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have animations playing in a view controller (via the `UIView.animateWithDuration` method). When I transition from the view controller to another using `transitionFromViewController`, the animations stop while the transition to the new view is taking place.

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Ive tried setting 
`UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` and `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowAnimatedContent` in the options, but as soon as the transition started all animations in the current view controller stop.

**Edit**

Also the fromViewController seems to be being removed from the container as soon as the method is called unless you specify an animation transition, where as I was the animated it myself.

Comment: Are you implementing this method in the first view controller? If so, is the first view controller acting as a container view controller? The documentation states "This method is only intended to be called by an implementation of a custom container view controller." You may have to do the transition by conforming to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransition` protocol instead.

Comment: This method is being called from the container view controller for the both views, as I understand thats where it should be called from "This method can be used to transition between sibling child view controllers." But as soon as its called the animations in the from view controller stop during the transition, and I can't understand why.